# streamset data collector container not able to read file from windows directory(d:/file)

Tags: docker, streamsets

I have created a container using docker and have that container running on localhost. All I want to do is to pick up an excel file from D:/file/ directory but when I enter such directory in Files Directory I get the error as no such directory exist. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it seems sdc only read local repositories. If you wants to read windows repositories, I think you can create an FTP origin. Try this, and hope this help.